# How can I get my Flash game to scale to all mobile device screen sizes?

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3

I want my application to automatically scale its size depending on the screen size. I want my application to fit any screen size automatically. I am making my application for mobile devices, how can I do this? I am fairly new at flash so please make it a bit simple!

Comment: Keep in mind, different devices have different aspect ratios, so it's not just a matter of scaling, it's also about positioning UI elements correctly, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use a framework like Starling that [supports this](http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/multi-resolution_development) out-of-box.